# Does ajax need contentType to send to php ? if so why error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I been trying to figure this one out but i don't seem to find the error but in my `script`

`My script`

```
$('#Bshift').click(function(){
 var isValid=false;
isValid = validateForm();

if(isValid)
   {
var ArrId= <?php echo json_encode($arrId ); ?>;
  var ArrQty= <?php  echo json_encode($arrQty ); ?>;
  var counter= <?php echo  json_encode($i ); ?>;
  var productId;
  var productQty;

  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    productQty = ArrQty[i];
    productId= ArrId[i];
   var pLocal= document.getElementById(productId).value;
   var prodData = 'pLocal=' + pLocal+ '&proId='+productId; 

   $.ajax ({
      url: 'shiftSave.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: prodData,
      dataType: 'json',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this is where  have the error 


        });

 }

     var pettyCash= document.getElementById("pettyCash").value;
  var comment= document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var prodData1 = 'pettyCash=' + pettyCash+ '&comment='+comment; 

      $.ajax ({
      url: 'shiftSave.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: prodData1,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8 ", // Error here too




      }).done(function(data){

          alert("Data Saved. Shift Started.");
          document.getElementById("register").reset();
          document.getElementById("Bshift").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("StartingB").disabled = true;


      }).fail(function(error){
        alert("Data error");
      });
     }



   });
```

Everytime i put the `ContentType` the script goes to done but if I take it off then my sql on my php executes and gives me a responce

`Php code shiftSave.php`

```
<?php 
        include "connection.php";
        session_start();
        $data=array();
        $location="";

        if (isset($_SESSION['location'])) {
        $location=$_SESSION['location'];

        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['eId'])) {
        $empId=$_SESSION['eId'];
        }


        if(@$_POST['pLocal']) {


        $proQty = $_POST['pLocal'];
        $proid = $_POST['proId'];
        try {


        $sql = "UPDATE location_product SET productQty='".$proQty."' WHERE productId='".$proid."' and productLocation='".$location."'";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Record updated successfully!";

        //$data["secion"]=$stmt. " this ";
        if ( !$stmt) {
         $data["match"]=false;
                } else {
        //echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;

        echo "Record updated successfully!";
        $data["match"]=true;

        }


        echo json_encode($data);



        } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data["match"]=false;
        echo json_encode($data);

        }

        }

            if (@$_POST['pettyCash']) {

                $pettyCashIn=$_POST['pettyCash'];
                $comment= $_POST['comment'];

                try {


                $sql = "INSERT INTO `customer_service_experts`.`shift` ( `empId`,  `pettyCashIn`, `note`) VALUES ( '$empId',   '$pettyCashIn', '$comment')";

                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                     // execute the query
                      $stmt->execute();
                if ( !$stmt) {
                $data["match"]=false;
                } else {

                    echo "Record updated successfully!";
                        $data["match"]=true;

                    }


                echo json_encode($data);

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $data["match"]=false;
                    echo json_encode($data);
                }

        }



        ?>
```

when i execute without the contentType it goes true but it fails and gives me Data error (the alert that i used on the function fail), but if I use the contentType it goes to the function `.done` and goes trough but the query does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to `stringify` the data you send like so

```
data: JSON.stringify(prodData1),
```

You could make a helper function which you can use everywhere you want to do a JSON POST

```
function jsonPost(url, data, success, fail) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: success,
        error: fail
    });
}
```

Comment: Does ajax need contentType to send to php ? if so why error?

Answer (score 0):

*Does ajax need contentType to send to php ?*

And you have a `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` which sends data in `request payload` but if you omit it/remove it from ajax then by default [contentType for jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

Lets see both of them here:

A request with `Content-Type: application/json` may look like this:

```
POST /some-path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{ "foo" : "bar", "name" : "John" }
```

And if you submit a HTML-Form with `method="POST"` and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` *(It is default for jquery ajax)* or `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` your request may look like this:

```
POST /some-path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar&name=John
```

So if you send the data in request payload which can be sent via `Content-Type: application/json` you just can't take those posted values with php supergloabals like `$_POST`.

You need to fetch it yourself in raw format with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the content-type option. Let jQuery use the default.
Second,

change:

```
var pLocal= document.getElementById(productId).value;
var prodData = 'pLocal=' + pLocal+ '&proId='+productId;
```

to:

```
var pLocal= document.getElementById(productId).value;
var prodData = { pLocal: pLocal, proId: productId };
```

and:

```
var pettyCash= document.getElementById("pettyCash").value;
var comment= document.getElementById("comment").value;
var prodData1 = 'pettyCash=' + pettyCash+ '&comment='+comment;
```

to:

```
var pettyCash= document.getElementById("pettyCash").value;
var comment= document.getElementById("comment").value;
var prodData1 = { pettyCash: pettyCash, comment: comment };
```